# how people graph a function?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Suppose, I have a function like this : $f(x,y)=5x+\sqrt{y}$

Simply what I do that is find $z$ axis for each possible numbers.

$$f(0,0)$$
$$f(0,1)$$
$$f(1,0)$$

But, it becomes very "hard" to find the axis and it takes lot of time to graph it. Actually, how a professional finds axis? I would like to find the graph without calculator (How professional graph it without calculator?).

Look how hard the following graph is

> [image]

Comment: In this case, it's easy to figure out what the contour lines are.  Have you done that?

Comment: The `directed-graphs` tag is for a different type of "graph", one which just happens to share a name with a function plot, so you were correct in not including it. What I do is compute the level set for some easy numbers, track where the function may not be defined, and visualize a rough image of the graph.

Comment: Because this function is a sum of two one-variable functions, I'd mentally sketch those first over a modest-sized rectangle, then sketch their sum.

Comment: Always try to figure out what the **level sets** (= sets of the form $\{(x,y): f(x,y)=\alpha\}$ for a fixed $\alpha$) look like. If you can do this, even in a fairly vague way (e.g. "they look like ellipses"), you'll get a pretty good picture of the graph.